# php/symfony/doctrine memory leak?

Tags: php, memory-leaks, symfony1, doctrine

I'm having problems with a batch insertion of objects into a database using symfony 1.4 and doctrine 1.2.

My model has a certain kind of object called "Sector", each of which has several objects of type "Cupo" (usually ranging from 50 up to 200000). These objects are pretty small; just a short identifier string and one or two integers. Whenever a group of Sectors are created by the user, I need to automatically add all these instances of "Cupo" to the database. In case anything goes wrong, I'm using a doctrine transaction to roll back everything. The problem is that I can only create around 2000 instances before php runs out of memory. It currently has a 128MB limit, which should be more than enough for handling objects that use less than 100 bytes. I've tried increasing the memory limit up to 512MB, but php still crashes and that doesn't solve the problem. Am I doing the batch insertion correctly or is there a better way?

Here's the error:

```
Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 71 bytes) in /Users/yo/Sites/grifoo/lib/vendor/symfony/lib/log/sfVarLogger.class.php on line 170
```

And here's the code:

```
public function save($conn=null){

    $conn=$conn?$conn:Doctrine_Manager::connection();

    $conn->beginTransaction();


    try {
        $evento=$this->object;


        foreach($evento->getSectores() as $s){

            for($j=0;$j<$s->getCapacity();$j++){

                $cupo=new Cupo();
                $cupo->setActivo($s->getActivo());
                $cupo->setEventoId($s->getEventoId());
                $cupo->setNombre($j);
                $cupo->setSector($s);

                $cupo->save();

            }
        }

        $conn->commit();
        return;
    }
    catch (Exception $e) {
        $conn->rollback();
        throw $e;
    }
```

Once again, this code works fine for less than 1000 objects, but anything bigger than 1500 fails. Thanks for the help.

Comment: mark someone's answer as correct, eh?

Comment: For bulk inserts you might also want to consider doing a raw SQL insert via PDO, it'll definitely be quicker, and it won't leak memory.

Answer (score 36):

Tried doing

```
$cupo->save();
$cupo->free();
$cupo = null;
```

(But substituting my code) And I'm still getting memory overflows. Any other ideas, SO?

**Update:**

I created a new environment in my databases.yml, that looks like:

```
all:
  doctrine:
    class: sfDoctrineDatabase
    param:
      dsn: 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=.......'
      username: .....
      password: .....
      profiler: false
```

The **profiler: false** entry disables doctrine's query logging, that normally keeps a copy of every query you make. It didn't stop the memory leakage, but I was able to get about twice as far through my data importing as I was without it.

**Update 2**

I added

```
Doctrine_Manager::connection()->setAttribute(Doctrine_Core::ATTR_AUTO_FREE_QUERY_OBJECTS, true );
```

before running my queries, and changed

```
$cupo = null;
```

to

```
unset($cupo);
```

And now my script has been churning away happily. I'm pretty sure it will finish without running out of RAM this time.

**Update 3**

Yup. That's the winning combo.

Comment: I'm having a similar problem. I tried these things and my performance improved significantly.

Comment: If possible, upgrade to php5.3 and use ->free(). The memory leaks are caused by PHP5.2's garbage collector not being able to clean away circular references that are no longer referenced from outside their loop. PHP5.3 has a better collector, and free() tries to undo those references before the variable leaves scope.

Comment: @Jordan - WOW i was just having a similar problem - but on a select - profiler: false had a HUGE impact ... thanks

Comment: +1 for the profiler tip. That was killing my app horrendously. Added the profiler:false and the peak usage barely changes even with many thousands of records

Comment: FYI, it is not really recommended to keep the profiler enabled on production.

Answer (score 3):

I have just did "daemonized" script with symfony 1.4 and setting the following stopped the memory hogging:

```
sfConfig::set('sf_debug', false);
```

Comment: This worked for me if you do it before you create the database manager. If you're in a task, I think this is safe.

Answer (score 3):

For a symfony task, I also faced to this issue and done following things. It worked for me.

- Disable debug mode. Add following before db connection initialize

  ```
  sfConfig::set('sf_debug', false);
  ```
- Set auto query object free attribute for db connection

  ```
  $connection->setAttribute(Doctrine_Core::ATTR_AUTO_FREE_QUERY_OBJECTS, true );
  ```
- Free all object after use

  ```
  $object_name->free()
  ```
- Unset all arrays after use `unset($array_name)`
- Check all doctrine queries used on task. Free all queries after use. `$q->free()`
  (This is a good practice for any time of query using.)

That's all. Hope it may help someone.

Answer (score 2):

Doctrine leaks and there's not much you can do about it. Make sure you use $q->free() whenever applicable to minimize the effect. 
Doctrine is not meant for maintenance scripts. The only way to work around this problem is to break you script to parts which will perform part of the task. One way to do that is to add a start parameter to your script and after a certain amount of objects had been processed, the script redirects to itself with a higher start value. This works well for me although it makes writing maintenance scripts more cumbersome.

Comment: I made the same experience that all those little tricks don't really help. I outlined a similar approach to yours: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11474869/620410

Answer (score 1):

Try to `unset($cupo);` after every saving. This should be help. An other thing is to split the script and do some batch processing.

Answer (score 1):

Try to break circular reference which usually cause memory leaks with

```
$cupo->save();

$cupo->free(); //this call
```

as [described](http://www.doctrine-project.org/documentation/manual/1_2/en/improving-performance:free-objects) in Doctrine manual.

Answer (score 1):

For me , I've just initialized the task like that:

```
// initialize the database connection
$databaseManager = new sfDatabaseManager($this->configuration);
$connection = $databaseManager->getDatabase($options['connection'])->getConnection();
$config = ProjectConfiguration::getApplicationConfiguration('frontend', 'prod', true);
sfContext::createInstance($config);
```

(WITH PROD CONFIG)
and use free() after a save() on doctrine's object

the memory is stable at 25Mo

```
memory_get_usage=26.884071350098Mo
```

with php 5.3 on debian squeeze

Answer (score 0):

Periodically close and re-open the connection - not sure why but it seems PDO is retaining references.

Answer (score 0):

What is working for me is calling the `free` method like this:

```
$cupo->save();
$cupo->free(true); // free also the related components
unset($cupo);
```