# doctrine and large amount of data

Tags: php, doctrine

i have a query that returns ~50k rows,
seems like doctrine put this whole result into memory what exceeds memory limit(128M)
the only solution i found that saves some memory is

```
$result->execute(array(), Doctrine_Core::HYDRATE_NONE);
```

but it still exceeds the limit,
is there any way to read one row at a time with doctrine ?

Comment: The first question to you would be - do you really need to query all those rows once? What are you trying to achieve? Maybe these calculations could be implemented in a query? And if its just for displaying, then you can really implement pagination.

Comment: this is to make xml feed

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Update:**
The below links are now dead, the current documentation is [here](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/3.1/reference/batch-processing.html)

[Doctrine Documentation - 13. Batch Processing](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/batch-processing.html) (DEAD)

**Update:**
For 1.2 check out this page:
http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine1/en/latest/en/manual/data-hydrators.html (DEAD)

Under the "On Demand" heading you will find the answer.

Comment: I guess its version 1.2 not 2.0

Comment: is there any solution for doctrine 1.2?

Comment: For me those tricks unfortunately didn't help substantially. Did it really solve your problem? I outlined another approach below. cheers

Answer (score 1):

**Batch processing helps!**

It took me a long time to figure out what helps. I have the impression that as long as you stay in the same php-process you can't free your memory. So *this didn't help* for me:

- $object->free(true)
- unset($object)
- sfConfig::set('sf_debug', false)
- gc_collect_cycles() / gc_enable()
- Doctrine_Core::HYDRATE_ON_DEMAND
- sfCommandApplicationTask::runTask()
- sfDoctrinePager

*What really helped* was [a hint from Rich Sage](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/symfony-users/4Z0BupPU4gQ/9F7WRw5udAMJ) who suggested to spawn subprocesses to execute Portions of the work. Limit and Offset for the query are given as parameters between the processes. To get row by row set `$options['limit']` to 1, but 50 should be a good value too:

**daddyTask.class.php**

```
[..]
$total = ItemTable::getInstance()->createQuery('i')->count();

for ($offset = 0; $offset < $total; $offset += $options['limit'] )
{
    passthru(
        sprintf('%s %s/symfony doTask --limit=%s --offset=%s', sfToolkit::getPhpCli(), sfConfig::get('sf_root_dir'), $options["limit"], $offset),
        $returnVar
    );
 }
```

**doTask.class.php**

```
$items = ItemTable::getInstance()->createQuery('i')->limit($options['limit'])->offset($options['offset'])->execute();

foreach( $items as $item )
{
    // ..do something with the item
    $this->log( 'INFO: '.memory_get_peak_usage(true).' memory in use.' );
}
```

*(I'm using Doctrine 1.2 in the Symfony 1.4 framework on PHP 5.3.10)*

Any comments or critique on this topic is greatly appreciated as it's a difficult one for me!

Answer (score 0):

is there a reason why you don't use ->limit() and ->offset()?

Comment: it will still use lots of memory, and will take more time. i'm writing to a file this result next