# Allowed memory size exhausted in Doctrine

Tags: php, symfony-1.4, doctrine-1.2

I use symfony 1.4 (from a task) and Doctrine 1.2 to import data from a lot of files.

It works well, but after a few minutes I get an "Allowed memory size exhausted" fatal error from PHP, not in my code but in Doctrine…

```
Call Stack:
    0.0004     325216   1. {main}() C:\wamp\www\XPower\symfony:0
    0.0125     587704   2. include('C:\wamp\www\XPower\lib\vendor\symfony\lib\command\cli.php') C:\wamp\www\XPower\symfony:14
    1.9202    6981872   3. sfSymfonyCommandApplication->run() C:\wamp\www\XPower\lib\vendor\symfony\lib\command\cli.php:20
    1.9233    6983528   4. sfTask->runFromCLI() C:\wamp\www\XPower\lib\vendor\symfony\lib\command\sfSymfonyCommandApplication.class.php:76
    1.9234    6983688   5. sfBaseTask->doRun() C:\wamp\www\XPower\lib\vendor\symfony\lib\task\sfTask.class.php:97
    3.0794    7047088   6. dataImportTask->execute() C:\wamp\www\XPower\lib\vendor\symfony\lib\task\sfBaseTask.class.php:68
    3.2731    8663752   7. dataImportTask->traiterDossier() C:\wamp\www\XPower\lib\task\dataImportTask.class.php:36
    7.7762   17906824   8. dataImportTask->traiterDossier() C:\wamp\www\XPower\lib\task\dataImportTask.class.php:55
  264.4390  133557080   9. xPower::importerXml() C:\wamp\www\XPower\lib\task\dataImportTask.class.php:64
  264.5919  133609328  10. xPower::importerFichierXml() C:\wamp\www\XPower\lib\XPower.class.php:312
  265.4313  134048568  11. InverterTable->findOneBySerialNumber() C:\wamp\www\XPower\lib\XPower.class.php:445
  265.4313  134048776  12. Doctrine_Table->__call() C:\wamp\www\XPower\lib\XPower.class.php:445
```

i've tried adding some "->free()" to Doctrine calls, but now it seems to fail on `InverterTable->findOneBySerialNumber()`, a "magic" Doctrine method.

How can I fix my problem ? Do I need to write my own "findOneBySerialNumber" method, adding a call to "free()" ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's such a common problem with doctrine. You have to use [pcntl_fork](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pcntl-fork.php).

I always use [this gist](https://gist.github.com/pborreli/396110) as an example.

`pcntl_fork` doesn't work on Windows because it requires an OS that follows the POSIX standards.

It might also be enought to just help doctrine free objects its objects, [here's a great answer about that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4066680/569101).

**If you got some `The MySQL server has gone away`:**

When using Doctrine and MySQL, it might be necessary to add the following of the child thread code:

```
Doctrine_Manager::connection()->close();
```

This will close the database connection, and Doctrine will automatically recreate it at the first query.

Comment: that's too bad. Now that I think about it, I have a lot of files now because it is the first import, if I run my task regularly I shouldn't have any problems.

Comment: I've update my answer with an other answer about freeing doctrine object, maybe it will be much easier this way.

Comment: Well ok, I'll try profiler: false and OH MY GOD everything is so fast now ! O.O lol nice tip, thanks :)

Comment: Great answer but I'm getting "mysql server has gone away". The accepted solution to this is to use mysql_close followed by mysql_connect... now need to figure out how to do taht with symfony.

Comment: ... got it. Edited answer accordingly.