# Symfony task - memory leak

Tags: php, memory-leaks, symfony1, propel

I wrote a symfony task to fill a database of sample data. Here's a sample piece of code:

```
gc_enable();
Propel::disableInstancePooling();

public function test()
{
    for($i = 0; $i < 10000; $i++) {
        $this->doIt($i);
    }
}

public function doIt($i)
{
    $user = new User();
    $user->setUsername('user' . $i . "@example.com");
    $user->setPassword('test');
    $user->setFirstName('firstname' . $i);
    $user->setLastName('surname' . rand(0, 1000));

    $user->save();
    $user->clearAllReferences(true);
    $user = null;
    gc_collect_cycles();
}
```

How can I limit the use of memory?

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2097744/php-symfony-doctrine-memory-leak

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have some good tips in [an other thread on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2097744/php-symfony-doctrine-memory-leak).

And here is a really good blog post about [memory leak using propel](http://www.pmsipilot.org/2012/01/13/eviter-les-fuites-memoire-avec-propel/). It's in french, but it's really interesting.

And, if you are working on big data (such as mass import) you should also took a look at pcntl_fork ([see this gist](https://gist.github.com/396110)). pcntl_fork doesn't work on Windows. I used this method to deal with big import and it's really fast and don't eat all your memory.

Comment: Danke, i used Propel::disableInstancePooling(); in wrong place. It should be inside method.

Comment: regarding pcntl_fork, I wrote a small library to ease the pain of using it: https://github.com/AZielinski/SimpleProcess

Answer (score 3):

This is final code. It could work inf amount of time at same memory usage level. Thx everybody.

```
public function test()
{
    for($i = 0; $i < 10000; $i++) {
        $this->doIt($i);
    }
}

public function doIt($i)
{
    gc_enable();
    Propel::disableInstancePooling();

    $user = new User();
    $user->setUsername('user' . $i . "@example.com");
    $user->setPassword('test');
    $user->setFirstName('firstname' . $i);
    $user->setLastName('surname' . rand(0, 1000));

    $user->save();
    $this->delete($user);
}

public function delete($obj)
{
    $obj->clearAllReferences(true);
    unset($obj);
    // redundant
    // gc_collect_cycles();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this, it works for me too. However, I noticed that gc_collect_cycles(); is not necessary, but it makes the code run slower.

Answer (score 0):

symfony CLI tasks require quite a lot of PHP memory, especially on Windows. If the Propel task is failing, I would recommend a permanent change to the php.ini file setting on memory allocation to at least 256M. I know this seems high, but you should only ever need these tasks on a development machine.