# Environment Specific Memory Leak

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm running into a memory leak issue during a batch processing script using Doctrine 2 /Symfony.

First: I AM aware how to properly manage the entity manager to avoid memory leaks, and for some reason my live server is able to run the following code without running into this issue. However on my local development environment (PHP 5.4.7) running the following command causes my memory use to balloon.

edit:

Is there any php ini, apache, osx, mysql confirguration that could possibly be causing this issue as I'm now at a complete loss.

Note that the code is the same in both locations - so the only thing causing this difference is some sort of logging (x-debug or automatic logging of SQL) that I'm unaware of.

live server is running PHP 5.4.6 vs 5.4.7 locally
live server is running centos 6, vs OSX locally

I'm running the following the command in prod mode with debug off...

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Bundle\MemoryTestBundle\Command;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Command\ContainerAwareCommand;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Output\OutputInterface;

class MemTestCommand extends ContainerAwareCommand
{
    protected function configure()
    {
        $this
            ->setName('mem:test')
            ->setDescription('Shows memory use ballooning out of control');
    }

    protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
    {
        $em = $this->getContainer()->get('doctrine.orm.entity_manager');

        $q = $em->createQuery('SELECT s FROM VendorMemoryTestBundle:SimpleEntity s');
        $iterableResult = $q->iterate();

        $i = 0;

        while (($row = $iterableResult->next()) !== false) {
            $i++;
            if ($i%50 == 0){
                echo sprintf('Memory usage: %01.0fKB.', memory_get_usage(true) / 1024) . PHP_EOL;
                $em->clear();
            }
            $em->detach($row[0]);
        }
    }
}
```

Output

```
Memory usage: 72192KB.
Memory usage: 72448KB.
Memory usage: 72448KB.
Memory usage: 72704KB.
Memory usage: 73216KB.
Memory usage: 73472KB.
Memory usage: 73472KB.
Memory usage: 73728KB.
Memory usage: 73728KB.
Memory usage: 73984KB.
Memory usage: 73984KB.
Memory usage: 74240KB.
etc...
```

Comment: what's the PHP version on the live server?

Comment: live = 5.4.6 ...... will update post

Comment: its interesting that you say you're using OSX on your local machine, the first thing I would assume is that its a bug in PHP 5.4.. but looking at the changelog it doesn't seem to have been resolved in 5.4.7 (at least no memory leaks are mentioned in the bug fixes), posting an issue on the doctrine2 github page is probably a good place to bring this up

Comment: I've been able to run the code on a colleagues system and there is no leak there (he's running 5.3.10 and a different php.ini). I've got the two system configurations so I'm going to use trial and error to work out what part of my configuration is causing the issue. I'll also get a VM up and running locally in Linux to try things out. I'll report back on the doctrine user group when/if I find out more.

Comment: I had a similar issue in doctrine 1.x using PDO with sql server, turned out it was a bug in PHP 5.3.6 which was causing a memory leak in PDO, might be a similar issue causing this

Answer (score 0):

As described here:
[php/symfony/doctrine memory leak?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2097744/php-symfony-doctrine-memory-leak)

In debug environment, Symfony logs all queries. You have to manually set the option "profiler:false."

```
all:
  doctrine:
    class: sfDoctrineDatabase
    param:
      dsn: 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=.......'
      username: .....
      password: .....
      profiler: false
```

Let me know if that helped. There are few other recommendations on the linked page, too; You might want to check them.

Comment: The link given is for Doctrine 1. I'm not running in a debug environment. The issue happens when I run in production mode (locally) and does not happen when my colleague runs the same code in production mode (locally). I'm sure it must be down to the way php is compiled (or my local configuration). I've never got to the bottom of this so I've just set my memory limit to 10Gb and let it fly for the time being.