# How to destruct an object in symfony 1.4?

Tags: php, object, memory, symfony-1.4, doctrine-1.2

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [php/symfony/doctrine memory leak?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2097744/php-symfony-doctrine-memory-leak)

I need to know if there is a way to destroy an object in symfony 1.4, because I have a cicle `for` that insert on database.

```
foreach ($array_data as $payroll_employee)
{
  $discounts = new PayrollDiscounts();
  $discounts->setPayrollId($payroll_id);
  $discounts->save();
  $discounts->free(TRUE);
  unset($discounts);
}
```

and display this Error:

> Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted

So I need to know a way to deliver memory.

Comment: Note that this is really a Doctrine (or Propel maybe?) issue rather than Symfony, I've added a tag.

Comment: How many items do you have in `$array_data` ? By the way, you should try every update from this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4066680/569101

Comment: @j0k Thanks your answer will be my solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have find the solution in these link:

[php/symfony/doctrine memory leak?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2097744/php-symfony-doctrine-memory-leak/4066680#4066680)

Thanks for all your advices!

Answer (score 1):

I've found it can be tricky to get Symfony to free memory, though you might try setting `$discounts = null;` instead of unsetting it (see [What's better at freeing memory with PHP: unset() or $var = null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/584960/whats-better-at-freeing-memory-with-php-unset-or-var-null)).

For simple bulk inserts like that I'd suggest doing the inserts with SQL (preferably PDO) instead of Doctrine.

Answer (score 1):

Using `unset()` will specifically free the memory associated with the variable, however I doubt that the setting of the `$discounts` variable is where you are running into your memory allocation issue, as it would have been overwritten with each pass of the loop.  Is `$array_data` itself too large? Is one of the methods executed on the `$discounts` object causing the problem?

Try to set some breakpoints in your code to better find where the memory problem is being encountered.

Answer (score -1):

You can destroy an object in PHP using `unset()`. That's what you are doing already.

In order to increase the memory available - you have to set the PHP config value

`memory_limit`

to a larger number.

Comment: increasing memory_limit is only a stop-gap solution.

Comment: Fair enough. But in my limited experience this is the only feasible way when there is a ORM in play.